# How does one find the cardinality of each element in a Cartesian product?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose we are given two finite abelian groups $G_1 = \mathbb{Z}_5$ and $G_2 = \mathbb{Z}_2$.

Let $\mathbb{Z}_5\times\mathbb{Z}_2 = \{(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1),(2,0),(2,1),(3,0),(3,1),(4,0),(4,1)\}$.

We know the cardinality of $\mathbb{Z}_5\times\mathbb{Z}_2$ is 10, so the elements of $\mathbb{Z}_5\times\mathbb{Z}_2$ could have the cardinalities: 1, 2, 5, or 10. And, we know that the only element with cardinality 1 is the identity element, i.e. $(0,0)$. Now, we are left with the remaining elements having cardinality of 2, 5, or 10.

How do we know which of the remaining elements have cardinality 2, cardinality 5, or cardinality 10?

Comment: It's called the *order* of an element instead of its 'cardinality'. Just find the smallest natural number $n$ that gives $n\cdot a=0$ for each particular element $a$. You will soon find an element $c$ of order $10$. There you can stop and consider the orders of $kc$ for each $k=1,2,\dots,9$.

Comment: For elements of a direct product, $G \times H$ then $|(g,h)| = \textrm{lcm}\{|g|,|h|\}$.

Comment: @eng2math If using |(g,h)| = lcm{|g|,|h|}, then using element (0,1), for example, would result in |(0,1)| = lcm{|0|,|1|} = 0. But an element having order 0 shouldn’t be possible because the only possible orders are 2,5,10. Are we supposed to do something with the 0 afterward?

Comment: @Berci I’m sorry for the late reply, I’ve been a bit busy today. I didn’t completely understand your response. I understood up until “you will soon find an element c of order 10,” where did c come from?

Comment: I gave that element a name. eng2math's comment might be more helpful for this exercise.

Comment: You have to be careful, the least common multiple is only defined for the naturals. The least common multiple of $a$ and $b$ is the smallest multiple which is divisible by both $a$ and $b$, hence we say $\textrm{lcm}\{0,a\}$ is undefined. @87days